# How to download a file in react js with blob object and how does featherjs can help handle blob as 'responseType'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, blob, feathersjs

If below format is used in axios calls , how can we achieve the same via feathersjs api call ?
Where do we need to specify the 'responseType' key ?

```
  return axios( {
    method: 'get',
    url: '_URL_',
    responseType: blob
  } );
}
```

I tried mentioning below code block for post request via create method from feathersjs doc:

```
 var config = 
      {
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       responseType: 'blob'
      }
    const response = _SERVICE_NAME_.create(data, config)
```

please help me to understand the format for mentioning responseType in request as a param in feathersjs